# Custom circular progressbar

Tags: android, progress-bar

I was able to create a circular `ProgressBar` to display my progress.

[image]

This progress bar will start from the top center point and moving right to left.

But now I have the need to modify it to look like the image below.

[image]

The ProgressBar is not a whole circle anymore, instead it will leave enough space for text display, and start from bottom left to right.

How can I make this happen?

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected.  Edit your question to include the code, please don't add it in a comment, as it will probably be unreadable.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are searching for [lzyzsd/CircleProgress](https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress) library.

```
<com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.ArcProgress
    android:id="@+id/arc_progress"
    android:background="#214193"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    custom:arc_progress="55"
    custom:arc_bottom_text="MEMORY"/>
```

[image]

You can customize it by attributes.

```
<declare-styleable name="ArcProgress">
    <attr name="arc_progress" format="integer"/>
    <attr name="arc_angle" format="float"/>
    <attr name="arc_stroke_width" format="dimension"/>
    <attr name="arc_max" format="integer"/>
    <attr name="arc_unfinished_color" format="color"/>
    <attr name="arc_finished_color" format="color"/>
    <attr name="arc_text_size" format="dimension"/>
    <attr name="arc_text_color" format="color"/>
    <attr name="arc_suffix_text" format="string"/>
    <attr name="arc_suffix_text_size" format="dimension"/>
    <attr name="arc_suffix_text_padding" format="dimension"/>
    <attr name="arc_bottom_text" format="string"/>
    <attr name="arc_bottom_text_size" format="dimension"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

Visit [github page](https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress) for more customization.